# How to store a userId in a session so that next resource is able to access it in Spring security

Tags: session, spring-security

I am working on Spring+struts2+hibernate integration using spring security for authentication. Here is the `application-security.xml` file:

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" filters="none" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/homePage.action" authentication-failure-url="/login-fail.jsp"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/logged_out.jsp" />
</http>
```

The issue is when user gets authenticated and request gets forwarded to `/homePage.action`, I am not able to get `userid` in `homePage.action` class (action class in struts).

Below is the code :

```
UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Debugged a code and found out that when request is forwarded to `/homePage.action`, `SecurityContextHolder` values are cleared.

Is there any way to make this `userid` available to `homepage.action` class?

I have searched a lot but couldn't finalise. Seems that I have to write some custom filter implementation and hook into spring security filter chain (so that session management is done at spring level only).

Can anyone give some pointer?

Comment: i think SecurityContextHolder values should not be cleared if user has been properly authenticated. filters="none" for all URLs?

Comment: SecurityContextHolder does hold UserDeatails after user authenticates successfully. filters="none" for all URLs will cause spring security to be bypassed,we cannot call any security related methods then.

Comment: You should probably clarify in your question why you want a login form but a completely unsecured application. Also, the login submission URL will be bypassed by this configuration. Can you actually login at all? Don't you get a 404 when you submit the login form?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you have to consider:

**First**, you have to have your filters from smallest to largest. Because if there is one filter matching the request, the rest of the filters are ignored. *See the problem in your configuration* 
**Second**, if the authentication is done successfully, `SecurityContextHolder` surly will contain the current user's `UserDetails`. *So there might be a problem with the authentication* 
**Third**, there is no such thing as `userId` property in `UserDetails`. (*I'm assuming that you are meaning something other than `username`*) So if you want his ID, whether you have to have your own class which extends `UserDetails` and put `userId` property in it, OR look up in your `USER` table (using `UserDetails.getUsername`) and retrieve his ID.

Comment: This isn't actually true. In Spring Security 3.0, the use of `filters="none"` in an `intercept-url` setting is independent of the access constraints so the order doesn't matter. Also, the `SecurityContextHolder` will *not* contain anything if the request bypasses the security chain (as it does here), regardless of whether the user has been successfully authenticated.

Comment: Hi, my changed application-security.xml looks like this, previous was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `application-security.xml` file (given below ), 
and problem seems to be resolved now.
Main change is from

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" filters="none" />
```

to :

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
```

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/inputUser.action" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/getDeleteUsers.action" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/login-fail.jsp" filters="none" />  
    <intercept-url pattern="/logged_out.jsp" filters="none" />   

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />  
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/homePage.action" authentication-failure-url="/login-fail.jsp"/>

    <logout logout-success-url="/logged_out.jsp"/>
</http
```

In spring security, `SecurityContextHolder` was filled up by `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` and hence it should pass spring security filter chain.
    (`filters="none"` will not work here as pointed out by Luke).

Adding `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />`
    makes sure that spring filter chain do gets applied when request goes for `login-submission` and `homePage.action`